# Combine multi rows in access - 1 field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have data in multiple rows, and I need to combine data in similar columns and separate with a semi colon, to end up with one row with grouped by ID.
I have
  ID     Type

1       A

1       B

1       C

2       D

3       A

3       F

I want results to be

```
1      A;B;C

2      D

3      A;F
```

I have limited knowledge of access, but know this should be basic and easy.  I appreciate assistance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConcatRelated function in a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940038/concatrelated-function-in-a-query)

Comment: Not really basic and whether it is easy is subjective. This is a common topic. Search web or SO site on the keywords `Allen Browne ConcatRelated function`.

Comment: I've searched and tried the ConcatRelated function, but can't get it to work.

Comment: "Can't get it to work" means what - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? The Allen Browne code is a proven technique. We have no information to assist with your issue. You must provide specifics related to your effort to implement the code. Edit your question.