# MS Access Concat on two Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi. Wanted some help on concatenating a table and joining it to another. Here's what I'm trying to do:

**Table1 - Users**

> ID | Users 
> id001 | User Name 1 
> id002 | User Name 2 
> id003 | User Name 3 
> id004 | User Name 4

**Table2 - Items**

> ID | Items 
> id001 | Item Name 1 
> id001 | Item Name 2 
> id001 | Item Name 3 
> id001 | Item Name 4 
> id002 | Item Name 1 
> id002 | Item Name 3 
> id004 | Item Name 2 
> id004 | Item Name 4

*********** OUTPUT ***********

> ID | Users | Items
> id001 | User Name 1 | Item Name 1, Item Name 2, Item Name 3, Item Name 4 
> id002 | User Name 2 | Item Name 1, Item Name 3
> id003 | User Name 3 | 
> id004 | User Name 4 | Item Name 2, Item Name 4

Comment: If this is for a report, it can do it right away. Just mark for the first fields: Hide duplicates.

Comment: Sorry, it's for a table.

Comment: And another duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18940038/concatrelated-function-in-a-query. Very common topic.